# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Set<String> Android

Tags: java

I declared my string as `Set<String> one;`.

Then I said `one = "string";`

Getting error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Set<String>`.

Any idea?

Comment: you declared one as a Set of Strings - it obviously can't be assigned with a String literal. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's because you cannot convert from `String` to `Set<String>` :)

Comment: I can't imagine how the error message could be clearer. Your variable is a set of strings, but you you're trying to assign to it a single string. You need to construct an actual instance of a set of strings; perhaps a hashset. Then you can add a string to the set.

Comment: Indeed.. The error message is very clear.. What else do you want from the compiler? Maybe next time it can invite you to a cup of coffee to discuss this :D

Comment: ok sorry dude my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add object to set like this....

```
Set<String>one=new HashSet<String>();
one.add("string");
```

Answer (score 2):

A Set of Strings is not a String.

Perhaps you wanted the method `Set.add()`?